# Which languages support while or do/while loops with automatic iteration indexing?

Tags: loops, for-loop, language-agnostic, programming-languages, while-loop

As the title suggests, which languages support while or do/while loops with automatic iteration indexing?

In other words a `[while]` or `[do/while]` loop that provides the iteration index automatically without having to resort to an intrinsically indexed construct such as the `[for]` loop. This was an odd question to Google which fetched out of context results.

Take the following as an example for C#:

```
int count = 0;
while (count < 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is iteration #{0}", count++);
}
```

As opposed to the following fictitious loop:

```
while<int> (value < 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is iteration #{0}", value); // Or value-- for that matter.
}
```

I do not know much about language design and thus the question. the `[for]` loop has a lot of flexibility but each kind of loop is best suited for certain scenarios. Still, it makes certain scenarios very odd such as combining iterators with indexers.

This is not meant to be an open-ended question. Simply, Do any languages support such constructs, and if not, ummm, cannot ask that here as that would make it open ended

**UPDATE**: I do realize the complexity that would arise out of nesting such loops but am sure that can be circumvented by some clever naming convention.

Something I had in mind but did not mention was the use of a clever lambda expression in the case of C# for example. That would not be an addition to the language but merely an extension (which I believe is only valid for reflection-friendly platforms such as .NET and Java).

Comment: If this question is not a good fit for the SO format, please advise where it should be asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby: `array.each_index{|i| print i }` will go  through each index.

Comment: Thank you @AShelly. I will read up on that construct. For now, it looks suspiciously like a lambda expression in C#. Is it a language construct or a language extension? I am not sure if Ruby offers reflection.

Comment: At [first glance](http://khelll.com/blog/ruby/ruby-reflection/), it appears to support reflection at least to some extent.

Comment: Ruby does support reflection. The block (the part in the curly braces) is essentially a lambda. Blocks are a core feature of the language.

Comment: Thanks again. Since this is an awkward question, I will wait for a day or two before marking an answer correct.

Comment: `10.times{|i| puts "This is iteration #{i}" }` and `100.upto(110){|i| puts i}` are some more Ruby examples.

Answer (score 1):

From my memory, the `DO` ... `LOOP` words in Forth supported kind of that.
The word to get the index of the current loop was `I` (obviously!) and that for the next outer loop was `J`.

Hence

```
10 1 DO I . 32 EMIT LOOP NL
```

would print:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```